# docment.forms["myForm"]["Element"].value command in js form validation

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I am making a simple Javascript  form validation and having trouble with accessing elements in the form. It seems that the command:

```
document.forms["myForm"]["un"].value;
```

works on Explorer but not on Firefox. The form I am working on is:

```
 <form name = "myForm" onsubmit="check()" method="POST">
            User Name:<br><input type="text" name = "un"><br/>
    Password:<br><input type="password" name = "pw"><br/>
    Confirm Password:<br><input type="password" name = "cpw"><br/>
            Email:<br><input type = "text" name = "em"><br/>
    <input type = "submit" id = "sub" value="submit">
```

And let js validation be:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
var user = document.forms["myForm"]["un"].value;
alert(user);
</script>
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. what is your question?

Comment: @DanielA.White really? Normally I'm pretty harsh with poorly-formed questions but I think this one is clear enough.

Comment: use document.forms["myForm"].elements["un"].value

Comment: `var user = document.getElementById("un").value;` `<input type="text" name = "un" id='un'>`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
var user = document.myForm.un.value;
```

I'm not sure if you've already heard of JQuery but I would recommend you use it. Check this out http://jquery.com/.

Comment: And why would you recommend jQuery?

Comment: @sachleen, I'm thinking he's just new to javascript and he can actually check out the jQuery library and take advantage of it.